# Create Windows Password Hint for a Domain User

Tags: windows-10, password, active-directory

Windows 10, if you don't type the password correctly, it will prompt you with a "password hint" that you set up (https://www.top-password.com/blog/set-password-hint-for-windows-user-account/).  But with a domain user, is it possible to set a password hint?

Comment: I think the appropriate choice would be to investigate either Microsoft or 3rd part password self-service (self-reset/unlock) solutions.  There is no situation where I would want a hint to be available for any single user on a domain.

Comment: Of course password hints aren't a good idea for security, and ill advisable. The question is ... can it be done and how?   The situation is to prompt which one of a users multiple passwords they should use eg: "use your domain password"